# How to alter the active text field in AS3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, textfield

I have 6 text fields on the stage along with a keypad with the numbers 0-9.

Ultimately this is going to be an Android app. And I want to be able the select a text field and then press the keypad buttons and have the numbers appear in the active text field.

I've been trying to Google active field and similar searches and can't seem to find a reference.

Keep in mind I'm fumbling around in the dark from what I've tried to gather from multiple tutorials. This code is probably complete garbage:

```
package  {

public class main {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.managers.FocusManager;
    var focus:FocusManager = new FocusManager(this);

    btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, inputNumber);

    public function inputNumber(m:MouseEvent){
            focus.text = 1;
    }

    public function main() {
        // constructor code
    }

}

}
```

Current Errors:

```
C:\Users\Otaku\Documents\lottocount\main.as, Line 19, Column 35 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:InteractiveObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.text:TextField.

C:\Users\Otaku\Documents\lottocount\main.as, Line 14, Column 44 1120: Access of undefined property onMyButtonClick.

C:\Users\Otaku\Documents\lottocount\main.as, Line 14, Column 3  1120: Access of undefined property btn_1.

C:\Users\Otaku\Documents\lottocount\main.as, Line 13, Column 47 1120: Access of undefined property onFocusIn.

C:\Users\Otaku\Documents\lottocount\main.as, Line 13, Column 3  1120: Access of undefined property stage.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the `focus` object, you'll have a reference to your currently active (focused on) object.

But in reality, just having a TextField that allows input will open a keyboard view (only on mobile) on touching it.

You can also tell Flash not to automatically show the keyboard, if you plan to use your own, then you can use the focus or make your own system that would track the appropriate TextField depending on where the last touch was.

**EDIT:**

Here's a simplistic example of how it could be done.
In this example I have two TextFields: tf1 and tf2. Also I've added a button for the sake of covering a situation where you need to save the last focus on a concrete type of object. The buttons name is myButton.

```
var lastSelectedTextField:TextField; // this will hold our last selected TextField

// make sure stage exists. If you're writing script in a frame, don't mind, if you use OOP approach you can do so by adding an eventListener for the event ADDED_TO_STAGE

stage.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn); // onFocusIn will trigger every time a focus is changed.
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMyButtonClick);

function onFocusIn(e:FocusEvent):void
{
    if (stage.focus is TextField)
           lastSelectedTextField = stage.focus as TextField;
}

function onMyButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Text of the last selected text field is:", lastSelectedTextField.text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still a little confused though. When I have multiple textfields up, and I click on one, does AS3 automatically track the current focus? In which case I would just have to code the number buttons to input the number into the current focus?

Comment: Yes, Flash tracks current focus, there are also event that will notify your objects that they got or lost focus. Please note that clicking the button will make the button gain focus ;) You probably want to make a condition that input will happen only if the current selection is type of TextField or what other class you want to use.

Comment: I'm having a major headache getting this to work. If I can get a partial example going I think I could start to get it better. Hang on, I'll upload a part of my code to my main post.

Comment: I'll make an example with 2 TextFields and a button for you, but after I finish my work here ;) You might need to wait for 1h.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your willingness to help a poor lost newb. :)

Comment: Thank you again! That does give me a much better idea of what I'm looking to do. However I'm still getting errors about types not being found. Included on bottom of my post.

Comment: make sure to import the classes that you need to use: flash.events.MouseEvent, flash.events.FocusEvent. Also make your main class extend Sprite or MovieClip (and import that class too)

Comment: I got that far doing some research, so those errors are now gone. But it's now telling me that we are accessing undefined properties. Which confuses me greatly. For instance my buttons instance name is btn_1, so I used that in place of myButton in your example. Isn't that instance name defined? (Current errors updated in post)

Comment: Sorry, but this is drifting into a whole other discussion. The code I've provided was tested and is working. Please make some effort to solve this problem yourself. The thing that you didn't knew how to import classes yourself tells me you're still in early stages of learning Flash. You should first spend some time to do tutorials, otherwise you'll get stuck in endless bug-fixing state. Just as a note: my example was written in a frame, GUI added directly on stage. Changing the button name won't brake the app, you can change the names of objects as you see fit.

Comment: Alright, I apologize. Thank you for the help you have given, it has indeed been useful!